# Smooth dependence of convex functions on Monge-Ampère measure

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ be a bounded convex domain, $f$ be a positive smooth function on $\Omega$ and $\phi:\partial\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. It is known that as long as $f$ does not tend to $+\infty$ too fast at the boundary, for every $t>0$ there is a unique convex function $u_t\in C^0(\overline{\Omega})\cap C^\infty(\Omega)$ satisfying
$$
\det D^2 u_t=t\,f,\quad u_t|_{\partial\Omega}=\phi.
$$

> **Question.** Does $u_t$ depend smoothly on $t$?